Trap handling in RISC V
Is there any way to handle the trap in HW.
mtvec is pointing to the  vector base address of the trap. In HW side how it will be point to specific trap?
In Interrupt handling, it jumps handler function using vector_base+mcause*4.
How the trap handled?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I am assuming that by trap you are referring to exceptions here. Spec mentions that trap code 0 should be used for it. Spec say in 3.1.7: When vectored interrupts are enabled, interrupt cause 0, which corresponds to user-mode soft-ware interrupts, are vectored to the same location as synchronous exceptions. This ambiguity does not arise in practice, since user-mode software interrupts are either disabled or delegated to user mode
